# Accessing google cloud storage bucket from cloud functions throws 500 error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to access google cloud storage bucket from cloud functions (python) instance and it's throwing mystic 500 error.

- I have given the service account editor role too. It didn't make any change.
- I also checked if any of the quota is going off limit. The limits were not even close.

Please, anyone can help me find cause of this error?

here is the code

```py
    from google.cloud import storage
    import os
    import base64

    storage_client = storage.Client()


    def init_analysis(event, context):
        print("event", event)
        pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')

        print(pubsub_message)
        bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
        for blob in blobs:
            print(blob.name)
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 99, in refresh service_account=self._service_account_email) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 208, in get_service_account_token 'instance/service-accounts/{0}/token'.format(service_account)) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 140, in get url, response.status, response.data), response) google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 500 Response:\nb'Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token\\n'", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x2b0ef9edf438>) The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 383, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 214, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 21, in init_analysis bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 227, in get_bucket bucket.reload(client=self) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 130, in reload _target_object=self, File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 315, in api_request target_object=_target_object, File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 192, in _make_request return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 221, in _do_request return self.http.request(url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 205, in request self._auth_request, method, url, request_headers) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 122, in before_request self.refresh(request) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 102, in refresh six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc) File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 500 Response:\nb'Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token\\n'", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x2b0ef9edf438>)
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 500 Response:\nb'Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/my-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com/token\\n'"
```

Comment: Has your Cloud Functions service account (service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com) the cloudfunctions.serviceAgent role? As you can see on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#cloud_functions_service_account) this service account need this role.

Comment: @TasosV I thought editor role covered all that. isn't that so? 
I just tried with all the cloud functions related roles assigned. It's throwing same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting it's because your Cloud Functions service account doesn't have the `cloudfunctions.serviceAgent` role. As you can see on [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#cloud_functions_service_account):

> Authenticating as the runtime service account from inside your function may fail if you change the Cloud Functions service account's permissions.

However, I found that sometimes you can not add this role as it doesn't show up as an option. I have reported this issue to the Google Cloud Functions engineering team and they are working to solve it.

Nevertheless, you can add the role again using [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding) `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_name> --role=roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent --member=serviceAccount:service-<project_number>@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```