# I'm not sure if this is Cloud Pub/Sub internal error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Recently I started to get this error when testing my Google Cloud function:

```
textPayload:  "2019/08/12 11:15:58 error publishing to the topic - rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = transport: compute: Received 500 `Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fpubsub"
```

It was surprise to me. Recenty I made some changes in the function, but it seems that was not the case. I reverted to the old code which was working before and I got the same error.

I read [Cloud Pub/Sub docs on errors](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes):

> INTERNAL  500 This error indicates an internal server error; it should not occur. If this error occurs, please report to cloud support. The error should be transient.

I reported it to the cloud support.

Still, I'm not sure is this Google Cloud internal error or the one induced by my code.

EDIT: Here is a pretty minimal code in Go.

```
package testfcn

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
)

func TestFcn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    ctx := r.Context()

    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, "min-fotball-staging")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("error creating PubSub client - ", err)
        return
    }

    topic := client.Topic("TestTopic")

    result := topic.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
        Data: []byte("TestMessage"),
    })

    _, err = result.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("error publishing to the topic - ", err)
        return
    }

}
```

And I have topic named *TestTopic*.

Comment: Make a small project/ pseudo code replicating the issue. Will help you to get some answers here.

Comment: @NarendranPandian I made it.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the same error message. Based on the error, it looks like your function is having trouble retrieving a service account token. What service account are you using to authenticate? Does it exist, and does it have the necessary permissions for publishing?

Comment: @Lauren That's the thing. It really looks like GCP bug. We tried with default account having _Owner_ role and with a dedicated service account having just _Pub/Sub Publisher_ role.

Comment: @SFin Just a suggestion. I do believe GCM was depreceated to make way for FCM?

Comment: @NarendranPandian You missed the point. GCM and FCM have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312091/accessing-google-cloud-storage-bucket-from-cloud-functions-throws-500-error looks like it could be related, can you see if that question resolves your problem? If not, could you provide some more information about your Cloud Function setup so we can replicate this error? What kind of Cloud Function trigger are you using? Did you change any function settings from the defaults? Also, about your Go setup: what Go version are you using and what is in your go.mod?

Comment: Thank you @Lauren and to the rest of Google Cloud Pub/Sub team involved. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a Cloud Pub/Sub client library's internal error.

Project's `service-<project_number>@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account had not assigned `Cloud Functions Service Agent` role.

It was not possible to add this role through Google Cloud Console, but by using `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_name> --role=roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent --member=serviceAccount:service-<project_number>@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Possibly useful links:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#cloud_functions_service_account
- [Accessing google cloud storage bucket from cloud functions throws 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312091/accessing-google-cloud-storage-bucket-from-cloud-functions-throws-500-error)
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1532

Extra:
In my case, this service account had `Owner` role. This means `Owner` role does not have some permission(s) `Cloud Functions Service Agent` role has.